# Ubuntu 13.04 Daily won't boot at all in upstream VirtualBox

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, virtualbox, 13.04

I managed to use Unity (slowly) and then installed Lubuntu. I restarted the machine and now I CAN'T GET X TO LOAD ON TTY7. I can switch to login terminals though. jockey-text tells me that I am using the kmod:vboxguest. I installed nvidia-common and tried to set it as default using jockey-text but jockey-text only detects the kmod driver.

I was going to report this on Launchpad but I don't think I understand about drivers in VirtualBox fully...can someone explain how to install and make default the nvidia-common driver in Ubuntu 13.04 Daily in VirtualBox?

System Specifications:

```
Guest RAM: ~1.5GB
Intel Pentium M Dual-Core @ 2.5GHz
NVidia GeForce 7050
```

Update 1: I rebooted and now I get `[ OK ]` in the top right with a flashing cursor.
Update 2: Found [this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090730030028AAIzAeK).  (Yahoo Answers post from 4 years ago that says that the virtual machine can't use things on your motherboard. Hmm).
Update 3: FIXED, just typed `sudo lightdm` in tty1 and that seemed to start it. (facepalm) 
Update 4: ...or not...tried 'sudo lightdm' and it just came up with a load of text ending in [OK] on tty7. Restarted and now it won't boot at all.

Note: I was going to answer myself but couldn't (due to a low rep cooldown) and now it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please add it as an answer and upvote+accept it. That way you get some reputation and others that see this question can directly see it has a workable solution (even it is as simple as you said ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using these commands should work:

- To start LightDM type: `sudo lightdm start`
- To Stop LightDM Type: `sudo lightdm stop`

If that don't work type: `sudo su`

- To start LightDM type: `lightdm start`
- To Stop LightDM  type: `lightdm stop`

Comment: Still doesn't work, see this Confirmed bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/969489

Comment: (Works sometimes)

Answer (score 0):

Just typed 'sudo lightdm' in tty1 and that seemed to start it... (facepalm)
Sometimes however, that doesn't work as a reliable workaround. lightdm got an update today and it doesn't fix the problem. Will report on Launchpad.

Comment: @Rinzwind Will accept this answer ASAP but I can't upvote my own post :P (great name btw, the ultimate coward indeed)